# How to lock line as horizontal/vertical in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I want to extend the fabric.Line class to ensure that it is always horizontal or vertical (depending on option during construction)

I'm ensuring this by overriding setCoords,

```
  setCoords() {
    if (this.orientation === 'horizontal') {
      this.set({ y2: this.y1 });
    } else {
      this.set({ x2: this.x1 });
    }
    super.setCoords()
  }
```

Which works fine when drawing the line, however it doesn't work when dragging the line. The line "jumps back" to it's original position when released.

Why does it jump back and is there a better way to ensure that my line always stays horizontal/vertical?

Answer (score -1):

Your method setCoords() works but you need to redraw the line when you drag the mouse.

In this example I created a function that draws the line based on a set of coordinates. Then the mouse event listeners call that function with the updated coordinates.

You will need to modify the orientation variable as needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
  
    <script>
  
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
        canvas.selection = false;
        var hvline = null;
        var coords = [];
        var dragging = false;

        var HVLine = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Line, {
                
            type: 'hvline',
            initialize: function(points, options) {
                options = options || {};
                this.points = points || [];

                this.callSuper('initialize',points, options);
                this.set('orientation', options.orientation || 'horizontal');
            },

            setCoords: function(ctx) {
                if (this.orientation === 'horizontal') {
                    this.set({ y2: this.y1 });
                } else {
                    this.set({ x2: this.x1 });
                }
                this.callSuper('setCoords', ctx);
            },
        });

        function drawLine(coords) {
            if (hvline != null) {
                canvas.remove(hvline);
            }

            hvline = new HVLine(
                coords,
                {
                    stroke: "blue",
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    hasControls: false,
                    hasBorders: false,
                    selectable: false,
                    lockMovementX: true,
                    lockMovementY: true,
                    hoverCursor: "default",
                    originX: "center",
                    originY: "center",
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                }
            );
            canvas.add(hvline);
        }

        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
            dragging = false;
            hvline = null;
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
            var positionX = pointer.x;
            var positionY = pointer.y;
            if (dragging) {
                coords[2] = positionX;
                coords[3] = positionY;
                drawLine(coords);
            }
        });

        canvas.on("mouse:down", function(event) {
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
            var positionX = pointer.x;
            var positionY = pointer.y;
            dragging = true;
            coords = [positionX, positionY, positionX, positionY];
            drawLine(coords);
        });

        canvas.renderAll();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```